# May someone enter a mikvah with a wheelchair?

Tags: mikvah-ritual-bath

I think my question would be more applicable for women than men, as women's mikvah is obligatory.

If a person is disabled and, say, has no one to assist going into the mikvah. S/he has a wheelchair and the mikvah has a ramp. Can s/he go with it into the mikvah, or is that considered chatzitza (intervening item)?

Comment: Source for the obligatory status of a mikvah? Does any body of water (be it an ocean, a sea or lake) apply as Mikvah? Depending on the grade of the disability I imagine it to be a great danger without assistance. How is said person to get out of the water with (or without) the wheelchair on its own?

Comment: It's obligatory for men too.  Just mostly not at the moment.

Comment: I read few articles on disabled women and Mikva, and no one came out with this idea. Is it practical?

Comment: Some mikvaot have been designed to be accessible to women with disabilities, incorporating devices such as hydraulic lifts. https://www.yoatzot.org/questions-and-answers/1611/

Comment: Florida Mikvah Installs Hydraulic Lift For The Disabled https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/general/23098/florida-mikvah-installs-hydraulic-lift-for-disabled-women.html

Comment: I don't understand how this is different from any other woman standing on the floor. (Aside from all the practicalities of a waterproof stable wheelchair moving underwater)

Comment: Just note that women traditionally do not go to Mikva without another women observing. So this case is not so common.

Answer (score 2):

[Y.D. 198:28](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.198.29?with=all&lang=bi):

> לא תאחוז בה חברתה בידיה בשעת טבילה אלא אם כן רפתה ידה כדי שיבואו המים במקום אחיזת ידיה ואם הדיחה ידיה במים תחלה שרי שמשקה טופח שעל ידיה חבור למי המקוה :
>
> Another woman should not hold her in hand while she is immersing, unless she loosens her hand so that water will come into the place where she is holding. And if she rinses her hand in the water beforehand, it is acceptable, because the liquid drops on her hand connect to the mikva water.

A very similar problem comes up all the time with tevilas kalim, immersing veseles that one bought from a non-Jew. Holding the glass (for instance) tightly is a chatzitza, and letting go of it will cause it to break. What to do? There are two options. 1) hold the glass loosely so that water could get between your hand and the glass. 2) get your hand wet before grabbing the glass.

Either one of these could be applied here. Get the wheelchair wet before the woman sits down, or for her to raise herself up just a little so water can get in between herself and the chair in the mikva.